# FFMPEG and DirectX Capture in C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, directx, screen-capture

I have a system that allows me to capture a window and save it as a mp4, using ffmpeg. I use gdigrab to capture the frame, but it is fairly slow (60ms per av_read_frame calls)

I know I can capture a game using the DirectX API, but I don't know how to convert the resulting BMP to an AVFrame.

The following code is the DirectX code I use to capture the frame

```
extern void* pBits;
extern IDirect3DDevice9* g_pd3dDevice;
IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface;
g_pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight,
                                      D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SCRATCH, 
                                      &pSurface, NULL);
g_pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);
D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
pSurface->LockRect(&lockedRect,NULL,
               D3DLOCK_NO_DIRTY_UPDATE|
               D3DLOCK_NOSYSLOCK|D3DLOCK_READONLY)));
for( int i=0 ; i < ScreenHeight ; i++)
{
    memcpy( (BYTE*) pBits + i * ScreenWidth * BITSPERPIXEL / 8 , 
         (BYTE*) lockedRect.pBits + i* lockedRect.Pitch , 
         ScreenWidth * BITSPERPIXEL / 8);
}
g_pSurface->UnlockRect();
pSurface->Release();
```

And here is my read loop :

```
{
    while (1) {
    if (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) < 0 || exit)
        break;
    if (packet.stream_index == videoindex) {
        // Decode video frame
        av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet, { 1, std::stoi(pParser->GetVal("video-fps")) }, pCodecCtx->time_base);
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

        if (frameFinished) {
            pFrame->pts = i;
            i++;
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
            pFrameRGB->pts = pFrame->pts;
            enc.encodeFrame(pFrameRGB);

    }
    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
```

How can I create an AVFrame using the bmp I have, without using the av_read_frame ?